# Best practices on go context cancelation functions

Tags: go, go-context

I have been reading some articles on the use of the context package from golang. I recently came across the following article in a blog: http://p.agnihotry.com/post/understanding_the_context_package_in_golang/

The article states the following regarding context cancelation functions in go:

> "You can pass around the cancel function if you wanted to, but, that
> is highly not recommended. This can lead to the invoker of cancel not
> realizing what the downstream impact of canceling the context may be.
> There may be other contexts that are derived from this which may cause
> the program to behave in an unexpected fashion. In short, **NEVER** pass
> around the cancel function."

However, passing the cancelation function as a parameter seems to be the only option in case I want the parent context.Done() channel to be activated (see the code snippet below). For instance, the code Done channel in the code snippet below is activated only when function2 is executed.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func function1(ctx context.Context) {
    _, cancelFunction := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    fmt.Println("cancel called from function1")
    cancelFunction()
}

func function2(ctx context.Context, cancelFunction context.CancelFunc) {
    fmt.Println("cancel called from function2")
    cancelFunction()
}

func main() {
    //Make a background context
    ctx := context.Background()
    //Derive a context with cancel
    ctxWithCancel, cancelFunction := context.WithCancel(ctx)

    go function1(ctxWithCancel)
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

    go function2(ctxWithCancel, cancelFunction)

    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

    // Done signal is only received when function2 is called
    <-ctxWithCancel.Done()
    fmt.Println("Done")
}
```

So, is passing this cancellation function actually an issue? Are there any best practices related to the use of the context package and their cancel function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your specific example, there's a small enough amount of code that there's probably no issue understanding how it all works. The problems start when you replace `function1` and `function2` with something more complicated. The article you link to gives a specific reason why passing around cancellation contexts can do things that are hard to reason about, but the more general principle is that you should try to separate coordination work (cancellation, spinning up goroutines) from the underlying work to be done (whatever `function1` and `function2` are doing) as much as possible. This just helps make it easier to reason about sub-sections of your code independently and can help make testing easier. "`function2` does <something>" is a lot easier to understand than "`function2` does <something> and also coordinates with `function1`".

Rather than pass the cancellation function into `function2`, you can just invoke it inside the goroutune you spawn to run `function2`:

```golang
func main() {
  //...
  go func() {
    function2(ctxWithCancel)
    cancelFunction()
  }()
  //...
}
```

This is niece because the coordination work of figuring out when to cancel is all contained within the calling function rather than be split across multiple functions.

---

If you want to have `function2` cancel the context conditionally, have it explicitly return some kind of value indicating whether some cancellable condition happened:

```golang
func function2(ctx context.Context) bool {
  //...
  if workShouldBecanceled() {
    return true
  }
  //...
  return false
}

func main() {
  //...
  go func() {
    if function2(ctxWithCancel) {
      cancelFunction()
    }
  }()
  //...
}
```

Here I used a boolean, but commonly this pattern is used with `error`s - if `function2` returns a non-nil `error`, cancel the rest of the work.

Depending on what you're doing, something like [`errgroup.WithContext`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup#WithContext) might be useful to you. This can coordinate several concurrent actions all of which might fail and cancels the others as soon as the first one fails.

---

One other best practice that I try to follow with context cancellation: always make sure that the cancel function gets called at some point. From the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/context#CancelFunc), it is safe to call a cancel function twice, so frequently I end up doing something like this:

```golang
func main() {
  ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
  defer cancel()
  //...
  if shouldCancel() {
    cancel()
  }
  //...
}
```

---

*Edit in response to comment:*

If you have a situation where you have multiple long-running operations (e.g., servers, connections, etc.) and you want to shut all of them down as soon as the first one stops, context cancellation is a reasonable way to do that. However, I'd still recommend that you handle all the context interaction in a single function. Something like this would work:

```golang
func operation1(ctx context.Context) {
   for {
     select {
     case <-ctx.Done():
       return
     default:
     }
     //...
   }
}

func operation2(ctx context.Context) {
  // Similar code to operatoin1()
}

func main() {
  ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
  var wg sync.WaitGroup
  wg.Add(2)
  go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    defer cancel()
    operation1(ctx)
  }()
  go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    defer cancel()
    operation2(ctx)
  }()
  wg.Wait()
}
```

As soon as one of the operations terminates, the other is canceled, but `main` still waits for both to finish. Neither operation needs to worry about managing this at all.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, you are right, this is an oversimplified example. I have a case in which a function initializes two modules: (1) establishes a gRPC connection and (2) establishes a WebSocket connection. I was wondering if it would be OK to use a contextWithCancel in order to detect if one of the connections goes down in order to shut down the other. Let me know if it makes sense to add an edit to the question.

Comment: Yes, I think that would be good context to add to your question. I'll edit my answer to try to address that kind of situation.